# How can I delegate a touchesbegan event to an entities component using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, sprite-kit, gesture-recognition

I'm creating a game for ios using swift. I've implemented the component entity system from Apples GameplayKit, very similar to how shown in [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/119959/gameplaykit-tutorial-entity-component-system-agents-goals-behaviors).

I have added a grid of squares which I want to respond differently to tap gestures. I will change a game state using state machine when a UI element is tapped, but I also want to then change how each square reacts to a tap gesture. From my current limited understanding, the best way to do this is change the tap gesture delegate. However, I've not been able to find any simple examples of how this can be done. The sqaures are SKSpriteNodes.

Code is available on request; however, I'm looking for an out of context example of how this could be done in the simplest way.

Does anyone know how this can be done or can suggest a "better" way. To avoid subjectivness, I'm defining better as structured better in terms of architecture. (Multiple if statements in a single gesture handler seems like the wrong way to do this, for example.)

Comment: If each square is a subclass of `SKSpriteNode`, you can set its `userInteractionEnabled` property to `true` and override its `touchesBegan/Moved/Ended` methods to receive touch events. You can then implement the square-specific effects (rotation, scaling, etc.) in the subclass.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a go. Each square that I'm seeing in the screen is an SKSpriteNode. I can access the node through the sprite component I created.

Comment: I suggest that you make your squares a subclass of `SKSpriteNode` so you can animate the square when touched and then call a method in the scene to handle the touch at a higher level, if needed.

Comment: I have done some work on this since posting. I'm trying to do as you suggested now. I'll update when I've either got it working, or come up against a barrier =]

Comment: If you have a Entity with component like SpriteComponent with node SKSpriteNode, in GameScene, when you touch a Entity, you can match the point of touch with the point of all entity in the array of entity in EntityManager. Now you have the focus on this entity and you can set the new state trough statemachine. I do not know if that's what you mean, you could post some code to better understand.

Comment: That is indeed how I intend to proceed @SimonePistecchia - I didn't post code because I wanted a general answer not specific to my situation. I will post code here once I have git it working.

Comment: I've managed to do what I wanted, however I'm not sure if it's the best way. I'll update with an answer which includes code soon, but briefly: When creating the spritenode, I attached the entity to the userdata attrbite of the node, which enabled me to retrieve it later on when getting all the nodes at the touch location.

Comment: @SimonePistecchia The problem for me was, the fact that you're actually touching the node, and not the Entity. The node is a variable that is part of the SpriteComponent, and I couldn't figure out a way (other than as described above) how to get from the node to the SpriteComponent or Entity. Did I miss something? If I understood your suggestion correctly, you suggested I loop through all the entities and check if the positions overlap? That seems suboptimal to me.

Comment: @Relequestual yes, I loop through all the entities and check if the positions overlap. I do this also for contact node. Because doen't exist contact between entity. I don't know if is the best way, I've read the apple documentation, the demo code of apple, ray tutorial etc, but i don't know... Ray's tutorial loop through all the entities every time. Some time this Gameplaykit seems elaborate, some time simple. I generally use delegate, but var node in SpriteKit, it can't have SKSpriteNode delegate.

Comment: @Relequestual The apple example doen't comunicate trought delegate between Component Entity. Now I have a problem with GKState, don't understand the best way to switch state...

Comment: @SimonePistecchia Right! I probably didn't mean delagate, as that's actually a reserved word in swift. I mean't, I want to delegate the action, not actually USE a delaget (becase as you say, there isn't one). I'll post my code when I can =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a working solution to my problem based on various bits of help and ideas I've had, however I'm still very much open to alternative solutions.

The main issue this probleme presnted, is how to reference back to the entity from the spritenode.
Through reading the documentation on SKSpriteNode, I discovered that it's parent class SKNode has a [userData attribute](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/userData), which allows you to store data in that node.

Attaching the entity instance to the node needed to happen in the SpriteComponent, as that is where the node is constructed, however it cannot happen in the constructor,so it had to be in a function in the SpriteComponent.

```
func addToNodeKey() {
    self.node.userData = NSMutableDictionary()
    self.node.userData?.setObject(self.entity!, forKey: "entity")
  }
```

Then the function is called in the Enity class construction after adding the compoennt to itself.

```
addComponent(spriteComponent)
spriteComponent.addToNodeKey()
```

Now the Enity instance can be accessed from the touch event, I needed a way to perform a function on that instance, however you don't know if the instance will be a subclass of GKEntity or not, nor which type.

Therefore, I created another component, TouchableSpriteComponent. After some trying, the init function took a single function as its argument, which is then called from the scenes touch event, which allows the entity which created the TouchableSpriteComponent to define how it handles the event.

**I created a [gist for this solution](https://gist.github.com/Relequestual/0a866211ef8d6ea93344), as there's probably too much code to place here. It is a permilink.**

I'd really love to know if this is a "good" solution, or if there's a much clearer route which would have the same effect (without looping through all the entities or nodes).

Comment: I recognise that the code contained in the gist isn't ideal in terms of swrapped and unwrapping variables. I'm still learning =]

Comment: Just FYI, all SKNodes (including SKSpriteNode) already has an "entity" property that you can set without having to dive into the userData dictionary.   (Ideally, loading a GKScene would populate this, but it doesn't, sadly, so you have to do it manually in code.)

Comment: Oh man. OK thanks. I'll give this a go the next time I work on the project =]

Answer (score 1):

If I understod well, you should have something like:

`func entityTouched(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)`

in your GKEntity subclass.

I do this in my game:

```
class Square: MainEntity {
    override func entityTouched(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        //DO something
    }
}
```

**GameScene:**

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)

    let touch = touches.first!
    let viewTouchLocation = touch.locationInView(self.view)
    let sceneTouchPoint = self.convertPointFromView(viewTouchLocation)
    let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(sceneTouchPoint)

    let touchedEntity = (touchedNode as? EntityNode)?.entity

    if let myVC = touchedEntity as? MainEntity {
        myVC.entityTouched(touches, withEvent: event)
    }
```

where:

**EntityNode:**

```
class EntityNode: SKSpriteNode {
    // MARK: Properties
    weak var entity: GKEntity!
}
```

**SpriteComponent:**

```
class SpriteComponent: GKComponent {

    let node : EntityNode

    init(entity: GKEntity, texture: SKTexture, size: CGSize) {
        node = EntityNode(texture: texture, color: SKColor.whiteColor(), size: size)
        node.entity = entity
    }
}
```

**MainEntity:**

```
class MainEntity: GKEntity {

    var entityManager : EntityManager!
    var node : SKSpriteNode!

    //MARK: INITIALIZE

    init(position:CGPoint, entityManager: EntityManager) {
        super.init()

        self.entityManager = entityManager

        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "some image")
        let spriteComponent = SpriteComponent(entity: self, texture: texture, size: texture.size())
        node = spriteComponent.node
        addComponent(spriteComponent)
    }

    func entityTouched (touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {}
}
```

Let me know if was what you are looking for.

Comment: I haden't considered subclassing SKSpriteNode to allow stroage of an entity, but I guess that actually makes sense. Is there any advantage to this implementation over my use of a nodes userData attribute?

Comment: I don't think that store the class in a dictionary is the best way to do this. Where are stored the data of userData? But I'm quite sure of this solution because Apple in DemoBoat use this approatc to  observe witch node is colliding. I think that apple's developpers are better than me! :)

Comment: I'll have a look at where DemoBots is doing this in the same way. I have looked at DemoBots. It does more advanced things than I think I will need for some things.

Comment: Yes, DemoBots does advanced things. But I've simplified my code above, it is easy to use, try it.